# Is it possible compile xcodeproj from web?

Tags: xcode, iphone, provisioning, xcodebuild

I'm trying compile project from web - I mean I have macos server, on my webpage i have button that running my bash script to build proj.
When I run from terminal

> `sh build.sh`

then it works fine, but when I run it from web - I have a lot of problems.

First of all I've copied distribution certificates in keychain to system from login (because web can't see login keychain).
But now, for start, I'm trying run clean up with next params:

```
(cd ${FOLDER}; xcodebuild clean -alltargets TARGET_BUILD_DIR=$target_dir)
```

and have next problem:

[BEROR]Code Sign error: Provisioning profile '7ADDCA00-6768-445F-8CED-368C4595657D' can't be found

Of course this provisioning is exsit, i've try param PROVISIONING_PROFILE, but i have same error.
I've try set this param to:

```
"/Users/skopanev/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/7ADDCA00-6768-445F-8CED-368C4595657D.mobileprovision"
```

and just

```
7ADDCA00-6768-445F-8CED-368C4595657D.mobileprovision
```

But have same problem.

Please tell me is it possible ?

thanks,

Answer (score 2):

It is theoretically possible to do what you want, but I have not tried. Your current error is probably a permissions error. The profile you specified is located in your user's Library directory, which the webserver is blocked from accessing. To fix it, either move the profile to some other location or change the permissions of *every* folder in the path so that the server can read it.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I've tried put provisioning in web directory, try wrote full path (absolute) from root /... and from web (relative) - have same error. How can I write profile name in params xcodebuilds?

Comment: As I see web it is user **stuff**, that is different with me. But I've opened to read only mobileprovisioning dir - `ls -l .../. provisiong` has a list of **MY** profiles. But have same error...

Comment: Any ideas ? Which parameter i should set to xcodebuild to use my mobileprovisioning ?

Answer (score 0):

I have made it:

I've used sudo -u USER that can compile on this machine. May be it is not safety, but it is work!